# Item '/system/mappings/schemas.json' not found for Localization '11' | Web 8.5 | DXA 2.2

Tags: 2013, dxa, web8.5, dxa2.2

We are upgrading Tridion 2013 to Web 8.5 using DXA 2.2

1. Upgraded existing CM to 8.5
2. Installed DXA
3. Installed [Standalone DXA Model Service](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20DXA-v12&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-2CF89E5B-D84C-498F-A65A-920EFC26A5A4&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-2CF89E5B-D84C-498F-A65A-920EFC26A5A4.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-2CF89E5B-D84C-498F-A65A-920EFC26A5A4)
4. Content ported necessary DXA modules into `Master Publication` of existing blueprint publication.

Installed reference DXA implementation on CME, published `400 Example Site` and able to request labels and sample page without any issues. I see the `BindaryData` folder for the `publicationId` is created with the required json files.

However, I am facing an issue while testing a sample page on the exiting upgraded publications. Model builder is generating without any component data.

```
{
"regions": [
{
"name": "Main",
"entities": [
{
"errorMessages": [
"Item '/system/mappings/schemas.json' not found for Localization '11'"
],
"isEmbedded": false,
"mvcData": {
"viewName": "EntityError",
"areaName": "Gea"
}
},
```

Error:

```
   Sdl.Web.Common.DxaItemNotFoundException: Item '/system/mappings/schemas.json' not found for Localization '11'
       at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Providers.Binary.CILBinaryProvider.GetBinary(Localization localization, String urlPath)
       at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Statics.BinaryFileManager.GetCachedFile(String urlPath, Localization localization)
       at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.GetStaticContentItem(String urlPath, Localization localization)
       at Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.Localization.LoadStaticContentItem[T](String relativeUrl, T& deserializedObject)
       at Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.LocalizationMappingsManager.GetSemanticSchema(String schemaId)
       at Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.Localization.GetSemanticSchema(String schemaId)
       at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.BuildEntityModel(EntityModel& entityModel, EntityModelData entityModelData, Type baseModelType, Localization localization)
       at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.ModelBuilderPipeline.CreateEntityModel(EntityModelData entityModelData, Type baseModelType, Localization localization)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.CreateRegionModel(RegionModelData regionModelData, Localization localization)
```

`Publish Settings` page and the sample test page is published properly and I can retrieve the PageModel data correctly but unable to transform into modelBuilder. Binary folder is **not** getting created for this `publicationId`.

**Edit 1 :**

Broker DB Data for both the publication. The one with 60 is `400 Example Site` which works fine. Other one is 11(old upgraded publication which is having issues)

[image]

```
{
    "defaultLocalization": true,
    "staging": false,
    "mediaRoot": "/media/",
    "siteLocalizations": [{
            "Id": "11",
            "Path": "/en",
            "Language": "English",
            "IsMaster": true
        }
    ],
    "files": ["/en/system/config/core.taxonomies.json", "/en/system/config/core.json", "/en/system/config/core.schemas.json"],
    "dataPresentationTemplateUri": "tcm:11-65100-32"
}
```

Are we missing anything here? any help appreciated!

Comment: Does it show in the database? Did you create the TTM mapping and baseURLs? what is the URL trying to access the webapp? Is that URL added to TTM website baseURL?

Comment: Hi @Velmurugan. It shows up on DB(attached/updated). Yes created TTM mapping and added base URLs. App runs fine and able to render the Pagemodel data properly. Just failing during  `CreateEntityModel` on `ModelBuilderPipeline` while rendeing DXA R2 model. That too for one publication(11 as specefied in the edit).

Comment: Try the following, try to restart the content service and discovery services, delete the BinaryData folder and restart the web app and then try again to see?

Comment: You can see that the URLs in the DB start with `/en/system`, whereas in the error message you see it is looking for a URL starting with `/system`. Please check the contents of `/system/config/_all.json`.

Comment: The issue seems to be with the default LocalizationResolver `CdApiLocalizationResolver` GetLocalization(ID) method. The `PATH` property of Localization is always empty even for '/en' publication. Overriding GetLocalization() to get right `path` variable fixes the issue. Now on `admin/refresh` BindayData is getting populated for all the publications. Was a nightmare!!

Comment: Customizing the `CdApiLocalizationResolver` should not be needed; it should work fine with Publication URL suffixes. The problem may lie in your Topology Manager configuration. Can you share the contents of `/system/config/_all.json` ?

Comment: Hi @RickPannekoek, Please find the contents of `en/system/config/_all.json` file.

Comment: Ok. And how does your Topology Manager Mapping for this publication look (`Get-TtmMapping` output)?

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would check would be file system permissions, to ensure that the identity running the app pool for the Example Site can indeed write in the BinaryData folder. If the user (I normally use Network Service for this pools) has access and the BinaryData folder is still not created, I would probably use my own Model Builder and overwrite methods accordingly to be able to debug locally.